# convert list to vector in r

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation

I have a list object of `NULL` and I would like to convert it as vector `NULL`. How to get around with it? Many thanks in advance.

```
myList <- list('A' = NULL, 'B'= NULL, 'C'= NULL); myList
```

Expected Answer

```
 A <- B <- C <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input already is a vector of NULL values

```
is.vector(myList)
## [1] TRUE

sapply(myList, is.null)
##    A    B    C 
## TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

so we assume that the question is asking to create objects A, B and C in the global environment with the values that the components of those names have in `myList`.  (If the current environment could be different from the global environment and you wanted them assigned into the current environment then use `environment()` as the second argument, instead.)

```
 list2env(myList, .GlobalEnv)
```